# Tunable parameters simulink

Tags: matlab, export, simulink, fmi

i am having problems exporting with standard FMI variables declared in the matlab workspace and used in a simulink model. in particular i can't figure out why the variables "soh" and "maxCap" are not exported (so it is not possible to change them after exporting as fmu) while others are.

```
soh = 93;
...
initSOC=95.20/100;
initBattTemp = 26.0271;
maxCap=maxCap0-maxCap0*(100-soh)/100;
initBattAge = 100*(100-soh);
```

also when i open the fmu export window both soh and maxCap are not shown

i have tried changing the "default parameter behavior" but whatever i do doesn't work.

Comment: Which FMI export capability do you use? The native solution from Mathworks, or FMI-Kit from Dassault Systems with Simulink Coder?